# take user id in all views with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

first sorry for my english cuz im from spain.
ok the problem is when i try to get the user in all views with appserviceprovider, this is my code

```
    public function boot() {
   $comprador =Auth::user();

    View::share('comprador', $comprador);}
```

and next i try to get the item in other view and the result is null

```html
   <div class="col-6 ">
{{dd($comprador)}}
    </div>
```

and this is the final result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsqqU.jpg)

Comment: You do not need to save it to a variable. You can use it the Auth facade, or the auth global helper directly in your blade views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to declare any variables you have the auth global helper that you can use anywhere. The code in your blade looks like this.

```
<div class="col-6 ">
  {{ auth()->user() }}
</div>
```

if you need lets say the name of the user its just `auth()->user()->name` etc.

Comment: its work, love u bro ;)  uwu

Answer (score 0):

```html
    
    
    
    
    
    userlistviewpage.php
    
    <table class="table table-hover">

    <thead>

      <th>Username</th>

      <th>Orders</th>

      <th>Balance</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
@foreach($users as $user)

        <tr>

          <td>{{$user->username}} </td>

          <td>{{$user->purchases}} </td>

          <td>{{$user->balance}} </td>


        </tr>
@endforeach

    </tbody>

</table>
```

```html
    Controller.php:

    public function boot() {
       $comprador = User::all();

        return view('profile.userlistviewpage', compact('users'));
        
        }
```